# Checking Model Relationships From Nested Resources

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

A common setup in Laravel routing is to use nested resources with route model binding. This allows great logical urls that represent the actual relationships that the models have with each other in the database. An example of this might be /library/section/book/. The book is owned by the section, the section is owned by the library. But when using route model binding, the ids of these resources are turned into models without any knowledge of each other. /1/7/234 would return the models of these resources but there is no guarantee that they are properly related. book 234 might not be owned by section 7 and section 7 might not be owned by library 1. I often have a method at the top of each controller that handles checking what I call relationship tests. This function would be found in the Book controller.

```
private function relationshipCheck($library, $section, $book)
{
    if(library->id == $section->library_id) {
        if($book != false) {
            if($section->id == $book->section_id) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return response()->json(["code" => 401], 401);
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return response()->json(["code" => 401, 401);
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to handle using these sorts of routes that represent relationships? Is there a more automated way to do this? Is there a good reason to just ignore everything but the last resource when the relationships are all one to many?

Comment: Related, for interest, to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358703/should-i-nest-routes-to-resources-in-laravel

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but still relevant today. There is a good answer [here](https://pineco.de/binding-relevant-models-to-routes-in-nested-laravel-resources/), which suggests explicitly binding the models in question. It's similar to another answer here, but with less abstraction.

```
Route::bind('section', function ($section, $route) {
    return Section::where('library_id', $route->parameter('library'))->findOrFail($section);
});

Route::bind('book', function ($book, $route) {
    return Book::where('Section_id', $route->parameter('section'))->findOrFail($book);
});
```

This will automatically work everywhere. If required, you could test for the upstream parameter to be found, and only perform the test in those cases (e.g. to cater for routes where only a book is specified).

```
Route::bind('book', function ($book, $route) {
    $section = $route->parameter('section');
    return $section ? Book::where('Section_id', $route->parameter('section'))->findOrFail($book) : $book;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> ...when using route model binding, the ids of these resources are turned into models without any knowledge of each other.

I am just starting to deal with this and here is how I've decided to make the approach.

- Make it easier to check a model's relations

  - Laravel 5.3 has a method to determine if two models have the same ID and belong to the same table. [`is()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3043)
  - I submitted a [pull request that would add relationship tools](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/14493). You can see the changes to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` that I am using in my project.
- Create a middleware for nested routes with model binding.

**Middleware**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Exception\HttpResponseException;

/**
 * Class EntityChain
 *
 * Determine if bound models for the route are related to
 * each other in the order they are nested.
 *
 * @package App\Http\Middleware
 */
class EntityChain
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Array of the bound models for the route.
        $parameters = array_filter($request->route()->parameters(),
            function ($v) {
                if ($v instanceof Model) return true;
                return false;
            });

        // When there are two or more bound models.
        if (count($parameters) > 1) {

            // The first model is the parent.
            $parent = array_shift($parameters);

            while (count($parameters) > 0) {

                // Assume the models are not related.
                $pass = false;

                // Set the child model.
                $child = array_shift($parameters);

                // Check if the parent model is related to the child.
                if ($parent->is_related($child)) {
                    $pass = true;
                }

                $parent = $child;


                // Fail on no relation.
                if (!$pass) {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json('Invalid resource relation chain given.', 406));
                }
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the need to do this before. This is how I've done it:

In my **RouteServiceProvider.php** file I have the following method:

```
private function addSlugBindingWithDependency(Router $router, $binding, $className, $dependency, $dependencyClassName, $dependencyField)
{
    $router->bind($binding, function($slug, $route) use($className, $dependency, $dependencyClassName, $dependencyField) {
        if (!is_string($slug)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException;
        }

        $params = $route->parameters();
        if (!$params || !isset($params[$dependency]) || get_class($params[$dependency]) != $dependencyClassName) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException;
        }

        $dependencyInstance = $params[$dependency];

        $item = $className::where('slug', $slug)->where($dependencyField, $dependencyInstance->id)->first();
        if (!$item) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException;
        }

        return $item;
    });
}
```

It's a function that helps me set up a route/model binding for a slug, where that slug depends on another part of the URL/path. It works by taking a look at the already bound parts of the route and grabbing the instance of the model it had previously bound and uses it to check that the two are linked together.

I also have another, more basic helper function, `addSlugBinding` that I use to bind a slug to an object too.

You would use it in the boot method of the `RouteServiceProvider` class like this:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    $this->addSlugBinding($router, 'librarySlug', 'App\Library');
    $this->addSlugBindingWithDependency($router, 'sectionSlug', 'App\Section', 'librarySlug', 'App\Library', 'library_id');
    $this->addSlugBindingWithDependency($router, 'bookSlug', 'App\Book', 'sectionSlug', 'App\Section', 'section_id');
}
```

Then in my routes file I might have the following:

```
Route::get('{librarySlug}/{sectionSlug}/{bookSlug}', function($librarySlug, $sectionSlug, $bookSlug) {

});
```

**Note:** I've done this when I've wanted nested URLs by slug rather than ID, but it can easily be adapted to use IDs.